# podspec setup for react native geolocation

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, cocoapods, podspec

Sorry for the noob question but I really have no clue how to setup this last bit of line for RN's Geolocation:

`If you are using CocoaPods for React Native, make sure to include the RCTGeolocation sub-podspec.`

I have a podfile already because I'm following guide from RNfirebase library,
but not sure where to add RCTGeolocation.

here's what I currently have:

```
target 'Absent' do
# Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use 
dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Absent
    pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.3.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 5.3.0'

  target 'AbsentTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

This is my first time customizing a project on mac and interacting with pod files.
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what you are supposed to add in your podfile:

```
pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
  'RCTGeolocation',
]
```

then run **pod install**

Comment: Thanks! that did it! I ended up needing to add a line for yoga too and add `RCTNetwork` to the subspecs of `React` but it ended up working thanks again :D

Comment: [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "React/RCTGeolocation":

Comment: Doesn't all react native apps have a podfile? If so, is this step compulsory for everyone? I am trying to debug my geolocation setup, from the same link OP: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html

Answer (score 1):

### Updated for 2019:

Install [react-native-geolocation](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-geolocation), and remember to `cd ios; pod install`.